# How to call static block of class in java

Tags: java, android

I have class which has static block as follows:

```
public class DataProvider {
static int a;
static String b;

static {
    a = readRollConfiguration();
    b = readNameConfiguration();
}


public static int getRoll() {
    return a;
}
}
```

I change configuration and call methods of this class then i get older values of **a** and **b**, until app is killed and restart.

So is there any way to call static block so that **a** and **b** get updated?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Remove all the "staticness" and do something less static. A cheap solution would be to create a static method that do what the static block do (but that's not super-safe)

Comment: The entire point of a static block is its executed only once-  when the class is loaded from disk.  If you want it to happen at other times, a static block is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the values of static variables `a` and `b` as part of `DataProvider` class initialization using a **`static` initializer block** and these values will be same unless you change the `static` values again.

So, update your `DataProvider` class and add `reloadRollConfig()` and `reloadNameConfig()` as shown below for reloading the values again from configurations:

```
public class DataProvider {
static int a;
static String b;

static {
    a = readRollConfiguration();
    b = readNameConfiguration();
}

 public static int getRollConfig() {//no reload, gets the current value
      return a;
  }

  public static int getNameConfig() {//no reload, gets the current value
      return b;
  }


  public static int reloadAndGetRollConfig() {//reload and get the new value
      a = readRollConfiguration();
      return a;
  }

  public static int reloadAndGetNameConfig() {//reload and get the new value
      b = readNameConfiguration();
      return b;
  }
}
```

---

> Yes, I know its bad idea, but configuration changes not very often.

I strongly suggest **you reload the values of `a` and `b` periodically** to set the latest values to the `DataProvider` class. You can do this by using a simple **scheduler** or implement a **caching layer** using frameworks like [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html). Caching frameworks provide many features for caching the static data and I suggest you need to **consider implementing caching** for this kind of configuration data (i.e., the data which does not change very often).

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are just loaded once. If you want to call the methods `readRollConfiguration` and `readNameConfiguration` every time you call the method `getRoll`, you have to call that method there.

```
public class DataProvider {

public static int getRoll() {
    return readRollConfiguration();
}
}
```

Comment: I know that way i can do but what is answer of my question.

Comment: this is probably a bad idea, getRoll result could change at each call and result in strange behavior in the app.

Comment: Yes i know its bad idea, but configuration changes not very often.

Comment: @Mundroid But static block will be executed once  at the time of loading, If you want it to re-execute, you have to compile that again.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use** *Class.forName("com.the.ClassName");*  **to call static block without ceating any instance of that class.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't call static block. It is called when Class object is created. You can think of it as constructor of Class object that describes your class. Unlike constructor which is called when instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done is completely wrong. static block will run only once whenever your class is loaded.

```
public class DataProvider {
    static int a;
    static String b;

    static {
        a = getSum();
        b = "15";
     }

    public static int getSum(){
        return 5 + 6;
    }

    public static int getRoll() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

So in this piece of code variable `a` will be created and assigned value `11` whenever `DataProvider` class is loaded. And, the point is that this value will be same until unless `DataProvider` class will not be recompiled or reloaded. Even, if the `getSum()` return new value each time, variable `a` gonna contain first value only.

So if you want `a` to be dynamic you have update variable every time you want to access `a` like this:

```
public static int get_a() {
    return  a = getSum();
}
```